# Is there a way to set the number of access attempts when using htaccess auth?

Tags: apache

Am trying to use htaccess for password protection and I got locked out after testing what would happen on a failed attempt.

Can I set the number of attempts allowed in the htaccess file? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http basic authentication - maximum allowed trial times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539430/http-basic-authentication-maximum-allowed-trial-times)

Comment: Not a duplicate since it doesn't give the answer I'm looking for which is  htaccess specific

Comment: Then please provide some more details. Do you know, how the server side is implemented? How are you locked out? Your browser displays the *Unauthorized* message? Or does the server refuse any further TCP connections?